# How can I check if there is a file inside a message and send it to another channel? [Discord.js]

Tags: discord.js

I need to check if there is an attachment inside a message sent by a user and if so, send this file in a specific channel.
for now I have only been able to check if the message contains an attachment, but I have not been able to send it to a channel

```
if(message.channel.name === "test-message") {
   const fileChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get("761217907518079026");
   if(!message.attachments) {
       message.channel.send("no attachment")
   } else {
       fileChannel.send("yes attachment");
   };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [`Message.attachments`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=attachments) returns a [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection), you can just use the [`Collection.first()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=first) method and send that.

```js
if(!message.attachments) message.channel.send("no attachment")
else fileChannel.send(message.attachments.first());
```